# How to run "rails s"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem running `rails s` in Ubuntu. When I type `rails s` it doesn't start the server, but instead it outputs:

```
kyala@ubuntu:~/depot$ rails s

Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  
-r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /home/kyala/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  
-d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)enter code here
                              # Default: sqlite3
 
 -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  
-m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails 

checkout
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails 

repository
      
[--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
 
 -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
 
 -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
 
 -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
 
 -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps


Runtime options:
 
-f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  
-p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
 
 -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
 
 -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist


Rails options:
 
 -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit


Description:
  
  The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
   
 directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
  
  rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

   
 This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    
See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to regenerate binstubs:

```
rm bin/*
rake rails:update:bin
```

It should do the trick.

For newer (5.2+) Rails versions use

```
rake app:update:bin
```

Comment: Rails 5.0.0.1 I had to run bin/rails app:update:bin. 

Any idea why this happens? I created a new branch, checked it out, did some work, came back to master and suddenly I could not run rails server any longer.

Answer (score 6):

When the script folder is missing from the Rails application folder it shows the above error.

I just copied it from another app and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Before running the Rails server, you need to first create a Rails application.

For example, to create a new app call "test_app", run the following:

```
rails new test_app
```

Once your application is created, you can cd into the directory and start your server:

```
cd test_app
rails server
```

Comment: i had already created a new rails application but every time I wanted to run the rails s it gives me that message :(

Comment: What is the output for `which rails`?

Comment: this is the output `/home/kyala/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails`

Answer (score 2):

My first hunch would be that you are not in the root of your Rails application.

On our deployment servers, I have to type

```
./script/rails s
```

when in the root-folder of my Rails-app. I think that is because `bin\rails` is not known there.

If that would not work, it seems to me that you are not at all inside a Rails root folder, which would also explain why `rails s` did not work.

A Rails root project will contain at least the following directories: `app`, `lib`, `config`, `script` ....

Comment: it gives me this error: `kyala@ubuntu:~/depot$ ./script/rails s
bash: ./script/rails: No such file or directory`

Comment: Then it would seem you are inside a rails application, in a standard rails app, there is a `script` folder containing the `rails` script. Could you verify that you are inside a rails application? What folders does it contain?

Answer (score 2):

OK guyz just for the closure... this problem occurs only when we delete some(mostly script) folders in the rails app... (may be.. accidentally.).. I had this issue but was in a wrong app folder...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar issue with Rails 2.x apps.  They fire up fine with `thin`, `unicorn` and such, but to get just the webrick server I've had to run `bundle exec script/server` (or for the less careful `script/server` seems to work).  I don't know the root issue at play here, but this seems to tide me over as I don't maintain any rails 2.x code (simply running ChiliProject 3.x, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem.

Be sure you run the 'rails' command in the script folder and not the binary 'rails' that is different

```
script/rails s
```

It´s the same that if you go to your script folder and run the command:

```
cd script
./rails s
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the 'script' folder exists in your application structure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I had forgotten to run bundle after creating an app.

From the root of your project directory run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

While searching for an answer myself, I ended up trying a few things that proved useful to getting `rails s` to work for me. This resulted in 658 files changed, 102204 insertions, and 149 deletions.

1. Look at the file that you're in by running `ls`.
2. Run `git status`.
3. Run `git add .`.
4. Run `git commit -m "Notate whatever changes you are adding to github repository"`.
5. I tried to run `git push` and `git push master` but neither work, "go figure." My guess is that you can't push changes that belong to a different file or branch.
6. HERE's THE SECRET... For some strange reason, I was working in a different file so I had to run a `git pull YourOtherFile`. This is where everything started making sense.
7. Now, I ran another `git status` to understand what was going on within this file. There was modified and untracked content.
8. Next, `cd` back into the other file.
9. Run `git status` to view all of your modified and untracked files.
10. Run `git add .` and `git commit -m "Notate your changes to this repository"`.
11. Watch the magic happen then run a `git push`.
12. Run `gem update bundler`.
13. Then I ran `gem install rails_12factor`.
14. Run another `git status` to view your modification.
15. Run `git commit -m "Successfully added gem rails_12Factor"`.
16. Run `git push`.
17. I had issues with bcrypt being locked at 3.1.11 so I ran `gem install 'bcrypt'`.
18. Run `gem install rails_12factor` yet again. I believe that I had the "f" in "factor" capitalized.
19. Run `gem update`.
20. Run `gem install pg`.
21. Run `git add .`.
22. Run `git commit -m "Updated Gemfile"`.
23. Run `git push`.
24. Run `gem install 'pg'` yet again.
25. I was running into all kind of issues but it was because I was trying to upgrade my gemfile to Rails 5.
26. Run `gem install railties`.
27. Run `gem install activesupport`.
28. If your Gemfile was already in another version of Rails (`gem 'rails', '4.2.6'`), make sure that you keep it there as there was not a significant difference in Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command inside your project folder:

```
rails s
```

Your project folder contains `node_modules`, `Gemfile.lock`, etc...

Answer (score -2):

Just Run 'bundle update' command and start your application

Answer (score -3):

Try "rails server" instead of the short form.  Maybe you have it aliased for some reason.

Comment: it prompted me with the same message.

Comment: `rails s` is short for `rails server`, not `rails start`.  The latter would produce an error message in any case.